# Inline scss variable as the name part in the evaluation of another scss variable

Tags: sass, scss-mixins, sass-variables

Suppose I have the following scss variables:

```css
$until-xs: "(max-width: 377px)";
$until-sm: "(max-width: 640px)";
...
$until-xl: "(max-width: 4000px)";
```

And based on them the following helper css classes are constructed:

```css
.until-sm {
  display: none;
  @media #{$until-xs} {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.until-md {
  display: none !important;
  @media #{$until-sm} {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

/* plus a lot of classes like this */
```

I am trying to create a mixin that would help me define those classes more easily by passing the `$until-x` variable as an input to the mixin, like so:

```css
@mixin until($x) {
  display: none;
  @media #{'$until-'#{$x}} {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Such that the classes above will be defined simply as:

```css
.until-xs { @include until($until-xs); }
```

The problem is the media variable inlining part does not evaluate the way I wanted, like:

```
#{'$until-'#{$x}} (when x is 'xs') =>
#{'$until-xs'} =>
#{$until-xs} =>
(max-width: 377px)
```

Any way I can achieve this? Since this can be applied in multiple places in my project I am more interested in the possibility of inlining vars like this than the solution to the particular problem from the example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining lots of variables like `$until-xs`, `$until-sm` and so on, you can define a **map** that contains information of your medias like the code below:

```
@use "sass:map";
$until-var: ("xs": "(max-width: 377px)", "sm": "(max-width: 620px)", "md": "(max-width: 807px)");

@mixin until($x) {
  display: none;
  @media #{map.get($until-var, $x)} {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
/* using that in your classes */
.until-xs { @include until("xs"); }

.until-sm { @include until("sm"); }
```

I'm not sure what you mean by **inlining vars**! But if you want a **single** mixin that works for different medias, I think that works.

Comment: That actually works with what I had in mind, thanks